# Not able to slide JQuery Mobile Slider in Ripple

Tags: jquery-mobile, ripple

This is really bugging me. I am using the Chrome Ripple Emulator to test my mobile app. And I can not change the value of the slider by sliding the button when using Ripple. If I disable Ripple I can slide the slider. Has anyone experienced this?

```html
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="height: 78px">
        <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" data-highlight="true" min="0" max="100" value="50" data-mini="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Kyle! did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No I did not. But I have not research this in a few months. You would have thought Ripple would have fixed this by now.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately no. it seems Ripple has problems with Sliders in general. If you use the regular HTML5 input type=range, without any JavaScript attached to it, it doesn't slide either..

Comment: Same happens to me when I use ripple in combination with the ionic framework